# Not able to fetch json data from a "SINGLE-TYPE" content-type in strapi

Tags: javascript, json, rest, strapi

I used strapi as my backend for all my data flow, I created single-type content, this single type has different components attached to it. After configuring all the single-types, I tried to fetch the data through rest Api, But I didn't got the json data as a response.

`This is my json response`

[image: This was the json response]

`This is my single-type structure`

[image: This is my single-type structure]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***So to get back all the data from the "single-type" the following procedure are:***

- After creating the **single-Type** content, Go to the settings of the strapi admin page and then click the **Role** option.
- Click on the public tab.
- locate **permissions** tab and search for the *single-type* you created and click on the single-type tab.
- Then you will find the permissions for that single-type, tick on **find** option, there are other option too, tick it as per your needs.
- After that you will see a api endpoint on the right side of the screen for that particular single-type.
- Copy that endpoint.
- Use your browsers or any api client like *Postman* etc to test the api endpoint.

***Now the Main Trick comes here***

To get the result of the end point you have to type something like this:

`http://localhost:1337/api/"your single-type name"?populate=*`

This above code will list all the components and all its data inside of it will be displayed in the json response.

**NOTE:**

If there is any **image data or any other media files inside the component** it won't be displayed, so to to get that also along with other data you need to type:

`http://localhost:1337/api/"your single-type name"?populate[your component name which contains that image data][populate]=*`

*When you type the api endpoint url your ***single-type*** name should be without double quotes*

Follow this link : [***For More Information regarding how to handle the rest api in strapi***](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#field-selection)